# Joomla update server with custom download url

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, one-click-updates

Is it possible to have a custom download url in the Joomla update server.

The help page says

```
<downloadurl type="full" format="zip">http://website.com/component.zip</downloadurl>
```

But I am thinking of having something like below

```
<downloadurl type="full" format="zip">http://website.com/component.php?downloadkey</downloadurl>
```

Comment: Have a look through this PR: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/2508

Comment: @lodder Thanks for pointing the link. Does he mean to change the core tables '#__updates' and '#__update_sites' by adding an extra column 'extra_query'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. [Akeeba Release System](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-release-system.html) (built for software distribution, mainly Joomla) uses URLs like this, and it works for me:

```
   <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">
      http://example.com/component/ars/?view=download&id=13&dummy=my.zip
   </downloadurl>
```

**But...**
I read somewhere that Joomla requires a file extension (`.zip`) for the url to work properly. I can't find the source right now.

ARS solves this nicely by adding an additional parameter at the end: `&dummy=my.zip`.